# Where do I find Crystal Reports 2011 or Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0 Documentation?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I'm trying to find the documentation for Crystal Reports 11 and seem to come up short.

Everything I've searched points to a tutorial or the beginners guide to Crystal Reports. I've only found 1 PDF that is Crystal Reports 10 and has some functions but doesn't seem to have all the functions. Does anyone know where I can get the documentation for Crystal Reports 11?

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, you may want to make sure you are not confusing product names.
Crystal 11 is very old. It has nothing to do with the .NET framework.

Crystal 2011 is a newer and quite different. Latest version is Crystal 2016.
Perhaps the info you are looking for is here:
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what version we are using, but I'm guessing it's 2011 or newer.

Comment: That link is not documentation. It does not provide explanation for functions available in formulas. You know where to find it?